# Save data into dll

Tags: c++, dll

i'm looking for some advice for "how I can store data into a dll" .

I want to do something like a database, but using a dll. Is it possible?

My scenario is:

An application load my dll, store a particular type of data and release it.
Another application, load the dll, read the data that the previous application has stored into it and use it.

The data type that I want to save is sensible one.

Any suggest?

Comment: You can not save persistent data in a dll

Comment: Sounds like a XY-problem for me, what are you trying to achieve actually? And no, it's not possible to do this with a DLL. The DLL just contains code, that is linked to executable programs at runtime.

Comment: You'll loose all the data as soon as the dll is unloaded.
But you can try to use shared memory, I suspect you are just trying to exchange data, not actually store it.

Comment: And the reason, that data saving into a .txt/binary/etc. file wouldn't work, is?

Comment: @DieterLücking your comment is the answer, you should post it as an answer yea?

Comment: @MasterAler I'm not trying to exchange data but I really mean that the dll will store some type of data and in a next time, another application (or the same application) will load the dll, read the data that is stored and used it.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius the data will contains sensible data and in a txt or in a binary the data will be more readable than stored in some type of dll or other.

Comment: But as  @DieterLücking says is not possible so i will find another method to do it.
Thank you all guys

Comment: @KingOfMazes Data stored in binary file is as readable as it would be if it were stored in a .dll file.

Answer (score 2):

You can not save persistent data in a dll.

Comment: Not applicable here, but you can distribute static data in a DLL like language string resources.